# sql query mass generation in excel

Tags: sql, excel

I am new here so please take it easy on me :)

I have an update query for SQL, but the problem is that I need to create hundreds of them, the same structure with different values in the columns and ID. The columns DPHExportovano and id_UzivatelDPHExportoval will be the same for all queries but the ones with equal sign will change in every query. Can I generate somehow many queries with these values? For example:

```
UPDATE p    
SET DPHExportovano='2020-02-01' 
, id_UzivatelDPHExportoval=2    
, CiziProdej=
, NepodlehaDPH= 
, ZakladDPH=    
, DPH=  
FROM Platba p   
WHERE p.ID=
```

[these values should be in the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIT1x.png)

```
0     142
0     0.01
17.13 16.27
3.43  3.25
14554 14581
```

Comment: The answer is "yes you can!", but what have you tried yourself so far ?

Comment: Don't?  Insert your hundreds of various values in to a table, and then run a single update that joins on your table?  *(Updating all the hundreds of rows at once?)*

Comment: What is the context? Where is this list of column names? What is executing the SQL: is it a program written in some language? You've tagged your question "Excel": what role does that play?

Comment: @Luuk I tried CONCAT but it worked for one query, I can not generate many of them. I just copy columns A+B, paste them to notepad, then delete B, and doing the copying again and again...

Comment: @MatBailie I do not know how you mean it

Comment: @DariusX. I use Sql Server SSMS
for example:
  CiziProdej= 0 
, NepodlehaDPH= -0.02 
, ZakladDPH= 55.1
, DPH= 11.2
, WHERE p.ID= 14653

I try to generate these queries in excel...

Comment: @DusanK: If you tried CONCAT, but it only worked for one query, why do you not add this info using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63797233/edit)-button to your question?, and if one query works, what about copying that line as often as you need it?

Comment: I already solved it, I just needed to have it transposed and put an empty column before every column very the vales are. Then just copied the UPDATE query like this:

UPDATE p SET DPHExportovano='2020-02-01', id_UzivatelDPHExportoval=2, CiziProdej= 51.03 , NepodlehaDPH= 0.36 , ZakladDPH= 388.85 , DPH= 77.77 FROM Platba p WHERE p.ID= 14703
UPDATE p SET DPHExportovano='2020-02-01', id_UzivatelDPHExportoval=2, CiziProdej= 12.65 , NepodlehaDPH= 0.09 , ZakladDPH= 68.99 , DPH= 13.80 FROM Platba p WHERE p.ID= 14601

Comment: Then just copied the UPDATE query like this:
Column A: UPDATE p SET DPHExportovano='2020-02-01', id_UzivatelDPHExportoval=2, CiziProdej= 
Column B: 51.03 Column C: , NepodlehaDPH= Column D: 0.36 Column E: , ZakladDPH= Column F: 388.85 Column G: , DPH= Column H: 77.77 Column I: FROM Platba p WHERE p.ID= Column J: 14703
this way I was able to generate as many query as I wanted in few seconds :)